# What are the differences between Pandemic and Pandemic 2013?

Tags: pandemic, expansions, edition-comparison

I have seen that there is a new edition of Pandemic for 2013.

What are the differences between Pandemic and the "New Challenge" version?

Can I convert my original edition to use any of the new rules?

Is the original Pandemic compatible with the 2013 expansion packs?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The differences between the original version of Pandemic and the 2013 version are essentially cosmetic. The only significant change is to the Role cards. The 2013 games features 2 new roles, **Contingency Planner** and **Quarantine Specialist**, that aren't in the original version. It also has the revised **Operations Expert** from the original *On The Brink* expansion. There are pictures of these cards [here](http://www.thezombiegame.com/forums/Thread-Pandemic-Revised). There have been some changes to the rulebook to clarify some things in the original rulebook that caused confusion.

The original Pandemic is not compatible with the 2013 expansion packs (the card backs have different designs), however you can buy [replacement cards](http://zmangames.com/nouvelles-details.php?id=309) to make the original Pandemic compatible with the new expansions.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the board art is also different and that's worth mentioning because if you buy the **In the lab** expansion you will end up with distinct board styles even purchasing the new cards.