# Pandemic 2012 or 2013

Tags: pandemic

I can't understand what is the difference between the Pandemic 2012 and 2013!
And do 2012 awards winning edition compatible with the expansions, or have a misprint issue?.

Comment: There is a Pandemic edition in 2012 and another one in 2013. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 3):

The second edition came out in 2013, the first edition in 2008. There is no 2012 edition. If you see it anywhere, then it's probably a typo.

There are differences between the 2008 and 2013 editions—for that, see [What are the differences between Pandemic and Pandemic 2013?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12508/what-are-the-differences-between-pandemic-and-pandemic-2013?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

Comment: Here is the back cover.  https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/~AwAAOSwHNxaGa8V/s-l500.jpg

Comment: It is the 2013 edition. The copyright is for 2012, but the game is from 2013. My 2013 pandemic also has a 2012 copyright.